# Rigidity of an open solid torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that $M$ is a 3-dimensional complete open Riemannian manifold
homeomorphic to a open solid torus. If $M$ has no conjugate point,
then it has a constant sectional curvature.

Is it right? Thank you in advance.

(This question is arise when I consider the following :
[Conjugate points in ${\rm Sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182994/conjugate-points-on-textsl2-mathbbr))

Comment: The product of a unit disk in the hyperbolic plane, by the circle gices you a solid torus but it does not have constant sectional curvature. Anyway this should be asked at MSE.